# Altering an array before output as JSON

Tags: php, arrays, json

I need to add a item and a key value to an array **once** during the `while` loop before it gets encoded to a JSON object, the output I have is this:

```
[
    {
        "sid": "1",
        "session_name": "Session Name",
        "session_open": "1"
    },
    {
        "sid": "2",
        "session_name": "Another session",
        "session_open": "1"
    }
]
```

But i need it to be like this:

```
[
    {
        "error": "none", <---- this part needs to be added
        "sid": "1",
        "session_name": "Session Name :D",
        "session_open": "1"
    },
    {
        "sid": "2",
        "session_name": "Another session",
        "session_open": "1"
    }
]
```

This is what I have when going through the `while` loop:

```
$sessions = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $sessions[] = $row;
}
mysql_free_result($result);

die(json_encode($sessions));
```

Comment: That's a pretty bad misuse of `die`... You should simply `echo` your json-encoded string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$sessions[0]['error'] = 'none';
echo json_encode($sessions);
die();
```

Interesting trick with the `die(json_encode())` there, please don't do it again. ;-)

Comment: Why is using `die(json_encode())` a bad thing? I'm making an AJAX request to the script, and all it has to do it just die with an output, what's wrong with using it?

Comment: @lol Certainly, it may work, but it's not what it was intended for. It also reacts differently should your `$sessions` happen to be an integer. These are the kinds of things that introduce hard to detect, cascading bugs. This particular example may not be too serious, but if it's representative of the rest of your code, abusing functions for purposes they weren't meant for is a habit you should kick. No offense. :)